# Why I cannot see the images?

Tags: wo2014044321a1

In reference to the patent: [WO2014044321A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2014044321A1)

How can I get the images?

Answer (score 1):

The site [www.google.com/patents](http://www.google.com/patents) is not always good with displaying patent figures. Better is [patents.google.com](http://patents.google.com). However in this case neither site seems to be providing images. My recommendation for searching patents is [The Lens](https://www.lens.org) (https://www.lens.org) which is usually the most reliable. In this case, you can find [WO2014044321A](https://www.lens.org/lens/patent/WO_2014_044321_A1) and see the entire PDF including figures and images. The Lens also provides additional features over Google that you might find useful.

[image]